# Any pool that value those who mine during low difficulty more?

Tags: mining-pools

Imagine a pool having 2 people.

A mines for 1 minute when difficulty is 1000. Then B mine for 1 minute when difficulty is 1. Let's for simplicity sake difficulty change from 1 to 1000 to 1 to 1000 to 1 to 1000 every minute. Say they both got the same machine.

Every 1-2 hours the pool solve some blocks.

The way I understand it is that the pool got far more contribution from B than from A. B contribution to solve some blocks is higher because B provides hash when difficulty is lower.

However, A and B will get roughly the exact same payment.

They submit the same number of shares for the same stratum difficulty.

Am I correct here?

This is important for those who are buying nicehash hash to sell to some other pool. Even though you time your buying when difficulty is low you are rewarded as much as anyone with worse timing,

Are there any pool that rewards you more when you mine at lower difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree with Murch's answer.

According to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4980.pdf

Only 2 kind of pools do that. PPS pool. And certain variants of PPLNS pool.

I got to ask the guy that author this.

Answer (score 0):

Difficulty doesn't randomly change all over the place. Difficulty is only adjusted every 2016 blocks.

Unless you're talking about the individual share difficulty the pool contributors are mining at: If `A` mines shares at difficulty 1000 and `B` mines shares at difficulty 1, the shares of `A` are worth 1000 times the share of `B`. If `A` and `B` have the same hash rate, `B` will find about 1000 times as many shares as `A`.

Obviously, each miner's individual difficulty should be adjusted to a level that they regularly find shares to communicate their contribution.

Not sure the rest of your question makes much sense to me: aren't miners paid out according to their contributed work and respective to the success of the pool? At lower difficulty, naturally the pool will find more blocks and the payout is higher.

Comment: Difficulty change rapidly on many alt coins.

Comment: I was assuming Bitcoin since nothing else was specified.